# Sort posts by post views and consider meta key

Tags: meta-query

my code should show popular posts where the meta key "slider" isn't empty. Have anyone an idea why it doesn't work?

The problem is that this code only shows posts with a slider image. But it ignores the sorting.

```
$values = array(
  'numberposts' => 10,
  'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
  'meta_key' => 'count_views',
  'meta_query' => array(
      array(
        'key'     => 'slider',
        'compare' => '!=',
        'value'   => ''
      )
  )
);

$my_posts = get_posts( $values );
global $post;
foreach( $my_posts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post);

   the_title();

endforeach;
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Answer (score 0):

The `SQL` looks correct. (You can substitute `new WP_Query` for `get_posts` and echo `$my_posts->requests` to see it.)

So I am going to guess that the sticky posts are making it look as though the sorting doesn't work. Add `'ignore_sticky_posts' => true` to your arguments.

Comment: I just looked if i have sticky posts. But there is not post where sticky is set to true.

Comment: You mean that you have no sticky posts set?

Comment: Yes exactly. I have no sticky posts.

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you missing one array in 'meta_query'? There should be an array inside in array. Take a look at http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters

Comment: Oh thanks you are right. Unfortunately it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The plug-in Wordpress Popular Posts could help you here - has some useful shortcoding you can call in PHP on various sidebars and widgets as well as measuring post views and comments.

http://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-popular-posts/

Not sure about sorting via meta key though as it has been a few years since I used it last.